# Allowed Origin is not working in case of putting dynamic String array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

I am using spring boot application and enabling CORS using corsfilter .

so when i pass static value to allowedorigin its working but when i put array inside it s not working.

please find my below which is not working code :

```
final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(dbProperties.getAllowedDomains());
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
```

dbProperties.getAllowedDomains() return List

and find code which is working:

```
final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://192.168.1.14:8080"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
```

Properties class below :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyProperties {
@Value("${alloweddomains}")
private List<String> alloweddomains;

private boolean enableMobileNotification;

public List<String> getAllowedDomains() {
    return alloweddomains;
}

public void setAllowedDomains(List<String> alloweddomains) {
    this.alloweddomains = alloweddomains;
}

}
```

Applicationtest.properties

```
alloweddomains="http://192.168.1.14:8085","http://192.168.1.15:8084"
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the `dbProperties` class and how you're setting the properties?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero sure @Value("${alloweddomains}")
 private List<String> alloweddomains;

Comment: @MarcosBarbero i am getting domain value on from dbProperties

Comment: Let me rephrase it, I need to see your dbProperties class and also your application.properties (or yaml).

Comment: see my edited post

Comment: Thanks! It will be very nice if you can also add the `application.properties`

Comment: i have added application.properties also see edited post

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor error here, you don't need the `@Value` as you're using `@ConfigurationProperties`, I also recommend you adding a prefix to the properties.

**EDIT**

Use camelCase for the variable name, instead of `alloweddomains` change it to `allowedDomains` and in the properties use `my-app.allowed-domains` instead of `my-app.alloweddomains`.

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my-app")
public class MyProperties {
   private List<String> allowedDomains;

   private boolean enableMobileNotification;

   public List<String> getAllowedDomains() {
      return allowedDomains;
   }

   public void setAllowedDomains(List<String> allowedDomains) {
      this.allowedDomains = allowedDomains;
   }

}
```

```
my-app.allowed-domains=http://192.168.1.14:8085, http://192.168.1.15:8084
```

This should fix it.

Working example: https://github.com/marcosbarbero/so-configuration-properties

Comment: after removing @Value now i am getting null value on alloweddomains

Comment: Did you add the prefix?

Comment: thanks but i have sloved my issue its because of "" which i am using on application.properties

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but if you're still using `@Value` within the `@ConfigurationProperties` class it's not how it's supposed to be done. I mean, you don't need a `@ConfigurationProperties` at all if you gonna use `@Value` in it.

Comment: yes i am using @Value only and its working fine with that

Comment: I just added a working example using the code above, you can follow it on the attempt to find where it differs from your code